# Python pandas creating datetime for Week and Year and Month and Year

Tags: python, pandas, plotly-dash, python-datetime

I'm have a pandas dataframe with : Branch, Year, Month, Week, Assignments, Sales Volume

I copied your format="%Y-%m" in the hope to get the same formatted datetime.. but no. In the following I will show you my code and the result of my formatted datetime column:

Code:
[image]

and this is my new year month datetime column:

[image]

I dont know why I am getting additional to my year and month **the day**...

Thank you in advance.

**Problem is solved many thanks to everybody for his help:**

Monty/Year and Week/Year Columns are working:

[image]

Greeting LittleStudent

Comment: try adding `errors='coerce'`  like this `dff['monthYear'] = pd.to_datetime(dff.Monat.astype(str) + '-' + dff.Jahr.astype(str), errors='coerce',  format='%m-%y')`

Comment: Hello Salahuddin,
I have the same formatting issue with your coude. I'm not getting the result month-year but year-month-day and I dont know why cause I used the code from you and I'm not getting the month-year format but instead  year-month-day....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. concatenate as strings with `'-'`
2. convert to datetime
3. reformat the datetime in plotly

```
df.head()
###
   Year  Month  Sales Volume
0  2020      1    773.956049
1  2020      2    438.878440
2  2020      3    858.597920
3  2020      4    697.368029
4  2020      5     94.177348


df['ym'] = df['Year'].astype(str) + '-' + df['Month'].astype(str)
df['ym'] = pd.to_datetime(df['ym']).dt.strftime('%Y-%m')

fig = px.bar(df, x='ym', y='Sales Volume', color=df['Year'].astype(str))
fig.update_xaxes(tickformat='%Y_%m', tickangle=45)
fig.show()
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you very much for your fast answers. I will test it as soon as possible.
Greetings LittleStudent

Comment: I used the format %Y-%m to format the date as needed and I and I'm not the result as you and it is the same Code:

Comment: I've updated the post as `pd.to_datetime(df['ym']).dt.strftime('%Y-%m')`, you may try it again.

Comment: It's working. Thank you very much Baron Legendre :)

Comment: And a datetime with week-years works too? I will try it now

Comment: And a datetime with week-years works too? I will try it now.
like : **dff['wy'] = pd.to_datetime(dff['wy']).dt.strftime('%V-%Y')**
But sadly it doesn't work. Thr error:
ValueError: month must be in 1..12

Comment: I just want to combine the year and week column to to display the sales volume in the same way like with the year_month but I have problems with the formatting

Comment: You may try this, `pd.to_datetime(dfw['Year'].astype(str) + dfw['Week'].astype(str)+'1', format="%Y%W%w").dt.strftime('%Y-%V')`